# Adding rel="nofollow" to joomla menu item

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, nofollow

I want to add the `rel="nofollow"` to the links on joomla menu item. This option is not available on administration backend. The robot add the attribute "nofollow" to the meta data of the page on that menu item not the actual link. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm using joomla 2.5

Answer (score 0):

You have to override method that show your menu items. In website there is many articles about that.

Answer (score 0):

Try these link:

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=470383

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/site-links/8733

Comment: Thanks, but most there are for joomla 1.5 - I'm using joomla 2.5

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to add any parameters to your menu items, you can accomplish this by overriding your menu module. In the menu module, check for the value of the robots parameter then add the appropriate rel to the link it creates.